# QueryDNS stuck, how to get out of UnexpectedNamingException?

Tags: apache-nifi

Using QueryDNS, some of my incoming flowfiles carry an "invalid" fully qualified domain name.
In this case the QueryDNS processor displays an ugly error message

```
Failed to process session due to Unexpected NamingException while processing records. Please review your configuration.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Unexpected NamingException while processing records. Please review your configuration.
```

It returns the flowfile to the incoming queue and will loop indefinitely yielding and trying to process the flowfile. Meanwhile other incoming flowfiles are stuck in the incoming queue and will never get processed since there are only "found" or "not found" relationships available with the processor.

How is it possible to get rid of these flowfiles (in NiFi 1.9.2), for example passing them to a LogAttribute processor ?

[QueryDNS stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nKIA.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get round this issue was to thoroughly clean/validate the hostnames/IPs I was looking up before it reached the processor.

If I'm honest the processor isn't really fit for purpose for any significant quantity of data. The problem you mention coupled with the lack of caching make it practically useless in production.

In the end we switched to using Logstash for our enrichment rather than NiFi, although, depending on your use case this may not be possible.